# Auto compile less css code when writing in Vim for Windows7

Tags: vim, windows-7, less

Follow the code and project for windows: https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows

ref: http://blog.dotsmart.net/2010/11/26/running-the-less-js-command-line-compiler-on-windows/

```
autocmd FileWritePost,BufWritePost *.less :call LessCSSCompress()
function! LessCSSCompress()
  let cwd = expand('<afile>:p:h')
  let name = expand('<afile>:t:r')
  if (executable('lessc'))
    cal system('lessc '.cwd.'/'.name.'.less > '.cwd.'/'.name.'.css &')
  endif
endfunction
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Vim solution (I have yet to start using Vim). But in case you're desperate for another solution maybe Watchr would work. Watchr claims to work with Windows. My opinion is that you might need Cygwin. When I did use Windows it was hard to detect file changes as they occurred.

https://github.com/mynyml/watchr